# SwiftUI - usage of toggles - console logs: “invalid mode 'kCFRunLoopCommonModes'” - didSet does not work

Tags: toggle, swiftui, didset

I have  a general problem using toggles with SwiftUI.
Whenever I use them I get this console error:

> invalid mode 'kCFRunLoopCommonModes' provided to CFRunLoopRunSpecific - break on _CFRunLoopError_RunCalledWithInvalidMode to debug. This message will only appear once per execution.

In addition to this didSet does not print anything when I hit the toggle in the simulator.
Does anyone have an idea, or is it a SwiftUI bug?

Other related questions on StackOverflow which are some month old didn't seem to find a solution.

```
import SwiftUI


struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var notifyCheck = false {
        didSet {
            print("Toggle pushed!")
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
            Toggle(isOn: $notifyCheck) {
                Text("Activate?")
            }
    }
}
```

If this is a bug, I wonder what the workaround for toggles is.
It's not as if I would be the first person using toggles in iOS. ;-)

Comment: like it's a bug somewhere in the UISwitch code in Xcode 11, It's happening in UIKit too

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Ignore that warning, it's SwiftUI internals and does not affect anything. If you'd like submit feedback to Apple.
2. `didSet` does not work, because `self` here (as `View` struct) is immutable, and `@State` is just property wrapper which via non-mutating setter stores wrapped value outside of `self`.

**Update:** do something on toggle

```
@State private var notifyCheck = false

var body: some View {

        let bindingOn = Binding<Bool> (
           get: { self.notifyCheck },
           set: { newValue in
               self.notifyCheck = newValue
               // << do anything
           }
        )
        return Toggle(isOn: bindingOn) {
            Text("Activate?")
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the information! Is there an easy way to implement a functionality which has the result that I tried to achive with above code (toggle triggered on-> do something)?

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your code just misses an "," : get: { self.notifyCheck },